# How to get value from controller back to $.Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

My setup: asp.net mvc web app

I am having trouble getting a value from a controller back to the $.Ajax call (see below). The controller deletes a record in a database and counts some other records.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: actions.action.RemoveItem + "?id=" + dataId,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
traditional: true,
success: function (result) {
    alert(result);
},
error: function (result) {
    alert("Error");
}});

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RemoveItem(int id)
{
    ... delete a record in the db
    itemsCount = .... counts of some other records in the db

    if (deletedRecord.id != null)
    {
        return Json(new { itemsCount });
    }
    else
    {
        return JsonError();
    }
}
```

The ajax call and the controller work properly, however when I try to use the returned value in the success function, the alert(result) gives [object object].
I have looked through all related posts, but could not find a solution that worked. Could someone give me a hint where the problem could be and how to make it work?
Thank you in advance and regards, Manu

Comment: If you try `console.log(result);` instead of alert you will get more hint about what you actually returned. Look in the browser console for the output (F12). Your result is a json object.

Comment: try to just return `itemCount` like `Json(itemCount)` it should work if your `itemCount` have value.

Comment: Because you are returning an object (with a property named `itemCount`). Use either `alert(result.itemsCount);` in the script or simply return just `return Json(itemsCount);` (and remove your pointless `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and `traditional: true,` options - your request is not sending anything in the body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result is a javascript object so alert works properly. If you want to alert it's structure as JSON use JSON.stringify() method like this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

If you want to access your itemsCount, just use dot or bracket notation:

```
alert(result.itemsCount);
alert(result['itemsCount']);
```